# Are there any books which show how to design electrical coil heat exchangers?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, heating-systems, heat-exchanger

I need to design an electrically powered gas heater, but i need to do so in detail. I'm looking for a guide similar to the shell and tube heat exchanger design guide in *coulson and richardson's chemical engineering design volume 6*.

Comment: The “real” constants are held by the heat exchanger manufacturers, so you will get close but not close enough... And I designed a heat exchanger for a process and was told by the manufacturer that I would not have got closer as the surface heat transfer coefficients given in text books are just an indication....

Comment: For a good reference, have a look at Siminson, Heat Transfer...

Comment: thank you very much for the reference